# File format converter library in Java

Tags: jax-rs, maven-plugin

I am trying to create a simple webservice in java that uses some library to convert the input docx file to an pdf file. Can some one please suggest me some sample libraries and also share some sample codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using Jersey, configure the file upload part of it. For it you need dependecy:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
```

After that you need dependecy of documents4j, I believe it is something similar as below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.documents4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>documents4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

You have more dependecy info here:

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.documents4j

After it in your servlet you should receive your file upload:

http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/file-upload-example-in-jersey/

And convert it to PDF:

```
File wordFile = new File( ... ), target = new File( ... );
IConverter converter = ... ;
Future<Boolean> conversion = converter
                            .convert(wordFile).as(DocumentType.MS_WORD)
                            .to(target).as(DocumentType.PDF)
                            .prioritizeWith(1000) // optional
                            .schedule();
```

https://github.com/documents4j/documents4j

For more docs you can look here:

http://documents4j.com/#/

For IConverter:

```
IConverter converter = LocalConverter.builder()
                           .baseFolder(new File("C:\Users\documents4j\temp"));
                           .workerPool(20, 25, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                           .processTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                           .build();
```

Comment: I am using JERSEY framework. can you please help me out with that.

Comment: What dependencies did you include in maven? Look at `documents4j-local
`

Comment: Yeah thank you now i got the error cleared but now I am getting an exception.java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create folder: C:\Users\documents4j\temp\bdb4c45d-c848-4efe-932d-e5eea44eecdc

Comment: You should create your own directory where the temporary files will be stored. Replace it with path to dir and put it at the line of ...baseFolder